# Send email to dynamically created group using workflow in SP Designer

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation

I have multiple groups on a site collection which look like following:

- IT_DEV
- HR_MGR
- FIN_ANLST

Each group has some members, whom I need to sent notifications, using a SharePoint workflow. However, the group name should be set according to a dynamically created value.

**Example:**

User creates a list item, filling in the required field values (e.g. IT to the Department field, DEV to 'Role' field and so on). Once item is submitted, WF takes this values, and creates a WF variable, which matches the available group (e.g. IT_DEV)

The issue is, that I cannot sent emails to the group which name values are set using the variables.

[image]

I also tried to create a 'User or Group' type of field, and set the variable value to the field. Didn't work as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, Did you found a solution to this ? facing the same challenge.

Comment: @AhmedBouchaala, yes I did. Please check the posted answer.

Comment: Got it Thanks, My Solution was to create a custom list where i store Users and Groups that we want to notify depending the document type. and then synchronise those field with SPGroups with an event receiver. With this we will be able to notify Users and Groups present in the UserGroupField.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution for the issue is the following:

1. Create SP List Field (e.g. NotificationGroup).
2. Set NotificationGroup field to the dynamically created group value.
3. Wait NotificationGroup to be not empty (using workflow actions).
4. Use the NotificationGroup field in the 'To' section, of the email sending window.

Feel free to ask is something is not clear.